# My function is executing later than assiging a varaiable to text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a counter badge for cart icon. But the thing is the $count variable is assigning to the text widget before executing the function so its returning null but i assign it to 0, for the first time. After switching to other screen and then to this screen then the value appears because the function executed you can see my icon badge code below. countForBadge() is my function and count is my variable , I don't know my function is future type maybe that's the reason

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_ui_kit/models/user.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_ui_kit/util/database_helper.dart';

class IconBadge extends StatefulWidget {

  final IconData icon;
  final double size;

  static int counteer;

  IconBadge({Key key, @required this.icon, @required this.size})
      : super(key: key);


  @override
  _IconBadgeState createState() => _IconBadgeState();
}

class _IconBadgeState extends State<IconBadge> {



//List _users;
  static int count ; 
  Future countForBadge() async{

    var db = new DatabaseHelper();

    count = await db.getCount();
    print("Count: $count");
    //print("khAN NNNN $counteer");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    countForBadge();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   if (count == null){
     count = 0;
   }

   print("Count lande: $count");
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          widget.icon,
          size: widget.size,
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 13,
              minHeight: 13,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
              child:Text(
                "$count",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 8,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, the reason it is not working is because it is a future. Do you need help finding a solution?

Comment: is it showing null or 0, as you are setting 0 if the count variable is null?

Comment: @MdGolamRahmanTushar It must be showing 0, but that's not the data that's in `countForBadge` which is want they want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the reason it is not working is because it is a future. A potential solution that I personally would use (not sure if it completely will work for you, it depends on your application) is the following modified `build` method - using a `FutureBuilder` to retrieve and show the `count` data:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          widget.icon,
          size: widget.size,
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 13,
              minHeight: 13,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: countForBadge(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    return Text(
                      snapshot.data.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 8,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                }
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

With this you can remove the static `count` variable and you won't have to do `countForBadge` in `initState()`.

An ***alternative*** method that might be easier for you to implement is to just call `setState` in `countForBadge` like so:

```
Future countForBadge() async{

  var db = new DatabaseHelper();

  setState(() {
    count = await db.getCount();
  });
  print("Count: $count");
  //print("khAN NNNN $counteer");
}
```

Comment: by returning count variable from the function countForBadge then i apply your first soloution and its worked for me, it also solve one of my other problem. Thank you very much